# Java errors, file not found and Error Aapt2

Tags: java, android, helper, aapt

Working with Android-Studio, I've received following errors and I'd like to know how they were created/how to resolve them.

First error:

> values.xml error: file not found

Second error:

[image: Image with the error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on how to ask a question.

Comment: I've updated the question to fit at least minimal requirements, however it would be great if you can copy/paste both error messages and also the part of code, where the errors occuring. Usually you should have 1 problem = 1 question, however if the problems are related, it should be alright to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your values.xml file is not present in your resources directory. If you have tried to import another project, make sure it is there.
If not create a new resource directory for the same.

1. Go to right portion of your Android Studio and click on Project Tab. From drop down menu select Android.
2. In your 'res' directory find the values directory. If you don't have right click and create a new Android resource directory. Make sure you select the type as values.
3. Finally create a resource file by right clicking on your values directory. Name it as 'values' and set type as 'values' as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: hello kaustubh Bhatter , thanks for replied my post, please 
how can I create a new resource directory for the file.

Comment: Thanks So Much Bro you helped me !! Thank you

Comment: Sure. My first answer here. Do mark it as the correct one if you got it right.
Glad to help!